# InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am making a map through google maps with the aim of showing 2 points on the map, one point is already predefined and the other point will be made using database coordinates.

The problem is that, even if the database coordinates are floated through the parseFloat function, google maps identifies the values ​​as NaN, since the alert works perfectly.

Database:

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_USUARIOS;
USE DATABASE DB_USUARIOS;
CREATE TABLE TB_USERS(
    USU_CODIGO INT PRiMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENTE,
    USU_LATITUDE FLOAT(10,7) NOT NULL,
    USU_LONGITUDE FLOAT(10,7) NOT NULL
);
```

```js
<?php
         $consulta=$MySQLi->query("SELECT * FROM TB_USUARIOS");
         $resultado = $consulta->fetch_assoc();
        ?>
        <html>
           <head>
           </head>
           <body>
              <div id="map"> </div>
              <script>
                 var latitude_cli = <?php echo $resultado['USU_LATITUDE'];?>; 
                 var longitude_cli = <?php echo $resultado['USU_LONGITUDE'];?>; 
                 alert(`${parseFloat(longitude_cli)} `);
                 alert(`${parseFloat(latitude_cli)} `);
        
                 function initMap() {
                    var ponto1 = newgoogle.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latitude_cli),parseFloat(longitude_cli));
                    var ponto2 = new google.maps.LatLng(36.522793, -83.212665);
        
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                    {zoom: 4, center: ponto2});
        
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: ponto1, map: map, 
                    title:"Produto"});
        
                    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position: ponto2, map: 
                    map,title:"Você"});
                    
                 }
              </script>
              <script async defer
                 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't reproduce your issue ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qtyrhnfv/17/)).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (preferably a StackOverflow code snippet in the question itself).

Comment: Please check out my answer below and let me know if it helps. Also, I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

What do your coordinates look like when you log out `latitude_cli` and `longitude_cli`? Make sure they are numbers or strings. The snippet below works without problem:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="height:400px;width:400px"> </div>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var ponto1 = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat("36.5"), parseFloat("-83.2"));
      var ponto2 = new google.maps.LatLng(36.522793, -83.212665);

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: ponto2
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: ponto1,
        map: map,
        title: "Produto"
      });

      var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: ponto2,
        map: map,
        title: "Você"
      });

    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```